# Adding a list of data to object inside loop

Tags: jquery, object, each

I have been attempting to add a list of values into a object/associative array so i can get a list of values from the input of a multiselect plugin. Im wanting to add the name of the input as the object key.

Problem: Doesnt seem to create a list, just updates the last input value in loop...what am i doing wrong here?

```
var selectObj = {}; 

$('input').each(function(inputKey)
{
    alert($(this).val());   //all input values shown
    selectObj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); 
 });

alert(JSON.stringify(selectObj));    //last input value shown
```

**Desired Results:**

- (1 multi-select):

> selectObj={"listName1":"12,3,31,4"}

- (2 multi-select):

> selectObj={"listName1":"12,3,31,4"},{"listName2":"1,32,43,5"}

Comment: Is the name attribute different for all the element? Otherwise it will just set the same property over and over and would explain why only the last input result shows. Hard to tell without seeing the markup.

Comment: Can you show the generated source  ? I suspect the multiselect plugin

Comment: Im using the name because it represents all multi-select inputs rather than the id of a single input...plus it works well with another plugin that uses the same name tag...plus i dont think i could set the id of each input via the options of the plugin.

Comment: @ gillesc : ahh it willl be the same, and is why it is replacing the existing value. This is on purpose tho, im trying to add the next value to the same list. The item name represents the list name, so many multi-selects can be used in the same form.

Comment: Ah, just create an array first then something like `if (!selectObj[$(this).attr('name')]) { selectObj[$(this).attr('name')] = []; } selectObj[$(this).attr('name')].push(value_here);`

Comment: Also probably assign `$(this).attr('name')` to a variable to avoid repeating the function calls.

Comment: **@gillesc:** Cheers your comment works perfect! Perhaps you could have answered my question so I can approve it...if you dont soon I will have to anwser my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **gillesc** for helping me solve this, it now successfully checks for all the input that has been checked or selected by various multi select plugins and outputs to the *inputValues* object:

```
$('input').each(function()
{
    if($(this).closest('li').hasClass("checked") || $(this).closest('li').hasClass("active"))
    {                 
        var selectKey = $(this).attr('name');                  
        if (!inputValues[selectKey]) 
        { 
            inputValues[selectKey] = [];
        } 
        inputValues[selectKey].push($(this).val());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do based on your edits of desired results

```
var selectObj = {}; 
var inputValues = [];
$('input').each(function(inputKey){
  attrName = $(this).attr('name');
  inputValues.push(value);

});
 selectObj[attrName] = inputValues .toString();
```

Comment: Is there not a way to create an array within the object so i can add values to the same list, instead of creating a new list name via itteration?

Comment: Yeah you could definitely do that, thats what I have edited in my answer. hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: This would be the solution for adding lists, but the inputs could include many lists/attrName and does not cater for this. Although gillesc solution in comments above does both!